# CSS - Can't control border color of Image Link

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, colors, border

I am facing a problem for many hours today, I can't get this fixed, maybe you can help me, I am trying to change the color of the border when hovering the mouse on a image inside link (`<a>` tag).

I am also using bootstrap.min.css for other stuff, but I managed to build a small test case so you can confirm the problem on your environment.

To simulate my problem I isolated all the code for a small test here it is:

**My HTML File:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="/Details/GetCategoryDetail/2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
    </a>
</body>
```

**My CSS File**

```
a:hover{

    border-color: blue;
    border-width: 10px;
}

a {    
    border-color:red;
    border-width:10px;
}
```

Anyway the color keeps the same (blue) every time I place the mouse hover the image. I did an inspect element using chrome, and there is the color selected "BLUE", not green neither red as I configured above...

This is very weird, I can't get it.
I also tried the following:

```
thumbnail a{
    border-color:red;
    border-width:10px;
}

thumbnail a:hover{
    border-color:red;
    border-width:10px;
}
```

**Didn't work..**

I even tried this one:

```
thumbnail a img{
    border-color:red;
    border-width:10px;
}

thumbnail a img:hover{
    border-color:red;
    border-width:10px;
}
```

**Also didn't work...** any clue about what is happening?
Thank you!!

Comment: You need to select the thumbnail class by using a period (do `.thumbnail` instead of `thumbnail`).

Comment: By the way can you explain me, when should I select the class (using '.') and when I don't need ? Or maybe send me a good tutorial about CSS I am feeling so dumb right now..

Comment: You use periods when selecting a class, pound symbols when selecting an ID, and you don't use either if selecting an HTML element (for example, there is no symbol to select either the `a` tag or `img` tag because they are raw HTML elements; if I had a class of `my-image`, I would select it with `.my-image`). [This tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_syntax.htm) might give you more insight too.

Comment: Thank you! I will read it, by the way I was testing with my class name, this should work right? 
a img {
 border: 10px solid red;
}

.thumbnail a:hover img {
 
 border-color:yellow;
 
}

I apply the border with width for the a img and then select my class to affect the border color?
But didn't work out, I will definitely read that one ;)
Thank u!

Comment: Never mind, I got it now! Here it is:
.thumbnail:hover img{
    border-color: yellow;
}

a img {    
    border: 10px solid blue;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the image and apply your border to the image, not the containing link tag. Your anchor tag in this case doesn't have a height/width, so a border cannot be applied directly to the anchor tag. Instead, apply a border to the image when the link is hovered on.

```css
a:hover img{
    border-color: blue;
}

a img {    
    border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="/Details/GetCategoryDetail/2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250/000/fff" alt="" />
    </a>
</body>
```

Comment: JEZZZ ! You are my life saver, I would be in this issue for the whole week, I didn't figured this out, the problem was the width/height of the parent tag. god damn it! thank you so much @SHBelsky ! Cheers !
EDIT: I will accept as soon as I can (need to wait few minutes)

Comment: Sure ! don't worry !

Comment: It's Done. Thank you.